# Ruby method that creates a large hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails.

I have a controller which make makes a subsequent request to an API that requires large array parameter with some values inserted.

I'm generating this parameter with a method that looks like this:

```rb
      def generate_params(search)
        [
          {
            script_score: {
              query: {
                neural: {
                  passage_embedding: {
                    query_text: search,
                    k: 100
                  }
                }
              },
              script: {
                source: '_score * 1.5'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            script_score: {
              query: {
                multi_match: {
                  query: search,
                  fields: %w[field_a field_b field_c field_d]
                }
              },
              script: {
                source: '_score * 1.7'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      end
```

The `search` parameter gets inserted into the array that is returned from the method.

My question is: What's the best practice for defining templates for large objects like this in Ruby / Ruby on Rails?

As you can see from the example, 95% of it is static template syntax, and only 2 values are populated by variables.

I want to reduce the method size to as small as possible, and was wondering if there is some way of defining this array as a template somewhere outside the method? Specifically what is the best practice approach in Ruby?

Comment: There's a lot of ways this could be done; which makes the most sense depends on context. Is there a compelling reason to code-golf the method?

Comment: Not sure I understand what "code-golf" means? Basically it's a request to the OpenSearch API which defines the query as a large DSL that is passed in as a JSON object. Basically I am generating this JSON object based on various queries/filtered passed to my API.

Comment: It means "why does it matter how small this method is".

Comment: Ah I see... Rubocop recommends it. I appreciate the question of if the length of a method matters is controversial, and I'm always willing to make exceptions if it's justified. In this case I was curious to explore alternatives approaches to break the method down.

Comment: This isn't a "normal" method; it's simply building some data. That said: if it were me I'd probably have a method for each query object with names that made sense int he context of the query language so they're easier to ID and reason about.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton appreciate the feedback. Yes you're right it's not a normal method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there's an agreed upon best practice, but I frequently see this kind of thing being stored in YAML files.

So if you create a YAML file with your configuration you can do something similar to:

```
require 'yaml'
my_configuration = YAML.load_file('path_to_yaml_file.yml')
```

This would allow you to treat the values of your YAML file like a hash:

```
my_configuration[:script_score][:query][:multi_match][:query] = 'some_value_or_method_call'
```

You can dump that in an array or whatever else you need to do with it - the point is that you can load most of your attributes via a YAML file and amend the object/hash as needed.

Alternatively, you could store the same attributes in a constant inside a module, load that module, and assign the search attribute that way.

Like I said, not sure if there's a best practice around this kind of thing, but I've seen both of those patterns numerous times in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course construct an array of the unique bits (each element of the array a hash) and then map those elements to the desired array.

```
def generate_params(search)
  distinct_elements = [ 
    { 
      query: {
        neural: {
          passage_embedding: {
            query_text: search,
            k: 100
          }
        }
      },
      source_score: '1.5'
    },
    {
      query: {
        multi_match: {
          query: search,
          fields: %w[field_a field_b field_c field_d]
        }
      },
      source_score: '1.7'
    }
  ]

  distinct_elements.map do |h|
      {
        script_score: { query: h[:query] },
        script: { source: "_score * #{ h[:source_score] }" }
      }
    end
end
```

```
generate_params('everywhere')
  #=> [
  #     {
  #       :script_score=>{
  #         :query=>{
  #           :neural=>{
  #             :passage_embedding=>{
  #               :query_text=>"everywhere",
  #               :k=>100
  #             }
  #           }
  #         }
  #       },
  #       :script=>{
  #         :source=>"_score * 1.5"
  #       }
  #     },
  #     {
  #       :script_score=>{
  #         :query=>{
  #           :multi_match=>{
  #             :query=>"everywhere",
  #             :fields=>["field_a", "field_b", "field_c", "field_d"]
  #           }
  #         }
  #       },
  #       :script=>{:
  #         source=>"_score * 1.7"
  #       }
  #     }
  #   ]
```